# Difficulty with factorizing determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

I came across this determinant and its just proved difficult to express as a product of in linear factors
$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\(b+c)^2 & (c+a)^2 & (a+b)^2 \end{vmatrix}$$
I have tried the basic operation combining rows and column but I can't just get to the answer $2(a-b)(b-c)(a+b+c)(c-a)$.
I  really need a guide or hints to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Let us call $\Delta$ this determinant. Do the following operation: replace the last column by its difference with the second one ($C_3\leftarrow C_3-C_2$) to get 
$$
\Delta=\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 &0\\a^2 & b^2 & c^2-b^2 \\(b+c)^2 & (c+a)^2 & (a+b)^2-(c+a)^2 \end{vmatrix}.
$$
Since $(a+b)^2-(c+a)^2=\left(b-c\right)(2a+b+c)$, we can use multilinearity of the determinant to get 
$$
\Delta=(b-c)\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 &0\\a^2 & b^2 & -(b+c) \\(b+c)^2 & (c+a)^2 & 2a+b+c \end{vmatrix}.
$$
Then We do $C_2\leftarrow C_2-C_1$ to get 
$$
\Delta=(b-c)(a-b)\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0&0\\a^2 & -(a+b) & -(b+c) \\(a+c)^2 & a+b+2c & 2a+b+c \end{vmatrix}.
$$
Expanding with respect to the first line gives 
$$
\Delta=(b-c)(a-b)\begin{vmatrix}   -(a+b) & -(b+c) \\  a+b+2c & 2a+b+c \end{vmatrix}.
$$
Doing $L_2\leftarrow L_2+L_1$ gives 
$$
 \Delta=(b-c)(a-b)\begin{vmatrix}   -(a+b) & -(b+c) \\   2c & 2a \end{vmatrix}
=2(b-c)(b-a)\begin{vmatrix}    a+b  &  b+c \\   c & a \end{vmatrix}.
$$
Finally, do $C_2\leftarrow C_2-C_1$ to get the wanted result.